# Run web-Socket locally for debug

Tags: go, websocket

I’m using gorilla web socket and I want to run it locally , I mean with the following chrome client
or other recommended tool …when I run into debug mode I got error

I use

```
"github.com/gorilla/websocket"


var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:  1024,
    WriteBufferSize: 1024,
}

upgrader.CheckOrigin = func(r *http.Request) bool { return true }

c, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Print("upgrade:", err)
    return
}
```

When I run the following url in chrome or web socket client I got error

websocket: not a websocket handshake: 'upgrade' token not found in 'Connection' header

```
localhost:8081/mypath
```

and I want to run it

```
ws://localhost:8081/mypath
```

and provide token for local simulation, how I can do it ?

To check it I use Simple WebSocket Client of chrome. any other client will be helpful

**EDIT:**

when I try it in the chrome console I got the following error:

> VM42:164 Refused to connect to 'ws://localhost:8081/mypath' because it
>   violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src
>   'self' uploads.github.com status.github.com collector.githubapp.com
>   api.github.com www.google-analytics.com github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com
>   github-production-repository-file-5c1aeb.s3.amazonaws.com
>   github-production-upload-manifest-file-7fdce7.s3.amazonaws.com
>   github-production-user-asset-6210df.s3.amazonaws.com
>   wss://live.github.com

Comment: here is the golang websocket tutorial which supplies above code and solves this question https://github.com/elliotforbes/tutorialedge.net/blob/master/content/golang/go-websocket-tutorial.md

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Browsers do not use the WebSocket protocol when fetching a web page for display. Code is required to use a WebSocket endpoint from a browser.

The Gorilla package includes [examples](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples) showing how to connect from a browser (the [chat](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/b89020ee79b89a7f932c5617d218fc06db382f53/examples/chat/home.html#L31-L45) and [command](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/b89020ee79b89a7f932c5617d218fc06db382f53/examples/command/home.html#L31-L45) examples are good places to start).

You can can connect to a WebSocket endpoint using the browser console:

```
> ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/mypath")
> ws.onmessage = function(ev) { console.log(ev.data) }
> ws.send("hello")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've tried it now and I got error, please see my edit, any idea?

Comment: Sorry after second try it works 1+ , is there a way to run it from unit test ? if yes can you provide example please?

Comment: @RaynD  Use net/http/httptest Server and Gorilla websocket client to use from test.  Ask new question for details.

Comment: Ok thanks, just last question in this context , how should I print the `hello` messge from the client inside the go file (ws handler) , I dont see it in the w obj...

Comment: Start with the read/write loop [at the beginning of the documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket).  After reading the message,  `log.Printf("%s", p)` to see the received message.

Comment: thanks, will try . btw as you suggested I open new query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47637308/create-unit-test-for-ws-in-golang , hope you can help. thanks!