# create unit test for ws in golang

Tags: go, websocket

I use the gorilla web socket framework and use the following client to run the web socket locally and debug it

https://github.com/gorilla/websocket

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/mypath")
ws.onmessage = function(ev) { console.log(ev.data) }
ws.send("hello")
```

This is working when I use it in the chrome console but my question if there is a way to do some unit test in go and avoid using the chrome console?

Comment: I haven't used gorilla or websockets, but you should be able to relax your test constraints, by initializing a server in your test (actually binding through the socket) and then using a test client in another go routine to interact with it.  This will at least allow you to verify your server is functioning using the websocket protocol and through the network stack, but of course doesn't verify that your server works through chrome..

Comment: @dm03514 - since I new to this topic it will be great if you can provide some example....thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Create a [test server](https://godoc.org/net/http/httptest#Server) using the [net/http/httptest](https://godoc.org/net/http/httptest) package. Connect to that server using the Gorilla client. Read and write messages to test the connection.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "strings"
    "testing"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{}

func echo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer c.Close()
    for {
        mt, message, err := c.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        err = c.WriteMessage(mt, message)
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
    }
}

func TestExample(t *testing.T) {
    // Create test server with the echo handler.
    s := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(echo))
    defer s.Close()

    // Convert http://127.0.0.1 to ws://127.0.0.
    u := "ws" + strings.TrimPrefix(s.URL, "http")

    // Connect to the server
    ws, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(u, nil)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("%v", err)
    }
    defer ws.Close()

    // Send message to server, read response and check to see if it's what we expect.
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        if err := ws.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte("hello")); err != nil {
            t.Fatalf("%v", err)
        }
        _, p, err := ws.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatalf("%v", err)
        }
        if string(p) != "hello" {
            t.Fatalf("bad message")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when I run `go tes` in the root I got the following error: `runtime.main_main·f: relocation target main.main not defined
runtime.main_main·f: undefined: "main.main"
`

Comment: I just create new golang project with this file and I try to run it...is it OK?

Comment: In a directory on your GOPATH, save the above to a file named `echo_test.go`.  From that directory, run the `go test` command.  If this does not work, then something is wrong with your local Go configuration. See [the Go documentation for more information about testing](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Test_packages).

Comment: Ok, thanks I did it PASS
ok      _/Users/i03333/go/webSocketClient      0.012s
How should I check myweb socket program ?

Comment: My question is how should I run it and it will stops at BP and the websocket code in my previous query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635764/run-web-socket-locally-for-debug

Comment: The code above shows the mechanics of testing a websocket endpoint using an example named echo.  Replace echo with your endpoint.  Replace the read/write loop in the test with whatever is appropriate for your endpoint.  I might be able comment further if you show the code for your ednpoint. Setting breakpoints in a debugger is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: The solution above works just fine. A tiny improvement I suggest:

I believe it's more elegant to parse `s.URL` as a `URL` struct using [`url.Parse`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Parse) and then change the scheme of the `URL` using `u.Scheme = "ws"`.

Here's a working example: https://play.golang.org/p/QiOkv8s608s

Comment: @IlijaEftimov  The string manipulation code is short, fast and handles both `http` and `https`. Although `https` is not used in this answer, I think it's important to show a conversion that will work with `https`.  See https://play.golang.org/p/0WXHNFOptkq for a more complete conversion based on `url.Parse`.

Comment: Too heavy solution. Need to find the way to mock "websocket.Conn"